# How to manage 2FA in selenium when we run the scripts in DevOps CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When we are running selenium scripts locally, the application uses Azure login(just mail id) and opens application home page. But when we are running same script in the pipeline, application is asking for username and password along with token number.

Could you please let me know how we can overcome this issue?

1. Created pipeline from DevOps
2. Added Maven and configured for running scripts